# Pip install returns "Could not find a version that satisfies requirement" for Artifactory uploaded package

Tags: artifactory, pypi

I uploaded a PyPi package to Artifactory local repository.
When i run

```
pip install -v package==0.1
```

it returns this error.

```
Looking in indexes: https://artifactory/api/pypi/pypi/simple
Collecting toolboxio==0.1
  1 location(s) to search for versions of toolboxio:
  * https://artifactory/api/pypi/pypi/simple/package/
  Getting page https://artifactory/api/pypi/pypi/simple/package/
  Looking up "https://artifactory/api/pypi/pypi/simple/package/" in the cache
  Request header has "max_age" as 0, cache bypassed
  Starting new HTTPS connection (1): artifactory:443
  https://artifactory:443 "GET /api/pypi/pypi/simple/package/ HTTP/1.1" 404 None
  Status code 404 not in (200, 203, 300, 301)
  Could not fetch URL https://artifactory/api/pypi/pypi/simple/package/: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://artifactory/api/pypi/pypi/simple/package/ - skipping
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement package==0.1 (from versions: none)
Cleaning up...
```

The pypi repository is configured to use simple-default layout during setup,

```
[orgPath]/[module]/[module]-[baseRev].[ext]
```

The artifact are uploaded to PyPi-local repository in this format

```
pypi-local -
           company/package - 
                           package-0.1.tar.gz
```

When I access

```
"https://artifactory/api/pypi/pypi/simple/package/"
```

in the browser, i can find the artifact.

When i use

```
curl -X GET "https://artifactory/api/pypi/pypi/simple/package/"
```

It returns

```
"errors" : [ {
    "status" : 404,
    "message" : "Not Found"
  } ]
```

I use Artifactory Set Me up, in my pip.conf

```
[global]
index-url = https://artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-local/simple
```

Artifactory Version : Artifactory Pro 6.8.1

I am unable to make the pip install work. Any ideas ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I managed to find a solution somehow, and i would like to share what i did.

Artifactory generated the pip.conf from Set Me Up function

```
[global]
index-url = https://artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-local/simple
```

Apparently, to access local uploaded files, you need to pass credentials to the index-url.

How to generate credentials to pass to the index-url.

1) Go to Artifactory.

2) Click Edit Profile. Generate API Key. Copy the API Key.

3) Edit the pip.conf file.

```
[global]
index-url = https://username:<API-KEY>/api/pypi/pypi-local/simple
```

4) Rerun pip install. It should work now.

Comment: Having a very similar issue, so even with anonymous access set up should this still be happening?